# How to set the number of seconds to start the video? Using the Re4act-Player library

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, video, react-player

[**enter image description here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIS5c.png)

**
I'm using a mp4 format video.**

Comment: Welcome. You need to give more pieces of information (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and give a reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example); if you can't, it's because you need to put more efforts and research; whithout those we can't guess your thoughts and your post will be quickly deleted by peers.

Comment: <ReactPlayer
        config={{
          file: {
            attributes: {
              controlsList: 'nodownload',
              poster: 'https://www.online-tech-tips.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/music.png',
            }
          }
        }}
        url={video}

      />
      <p>{secondsToHms(tempo)}</p>

Comment: I need to set a video start value

Comment: You want to edit you question and add the code, and explain where you are (where are you stuck), where you want to go (what you want to achieve). Comments are for commenting the post, mostly answer hints or so.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Please [edit] your question to post your code as text.